# Do I need to create a new PrintWriter instance to see each write to file?

Tags: java

I have a long running process where I want to continually write to a file and see the output as I go. Basically logging. (I cannot use any logging frameworks) Unless I call `close()` on `PrintWriter`, I do not see anything new in the file.

Must I create a new instance of `PrintWriter` each time I want to see the output in the file? I may have hundreds of writes.

```
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(new File("F.txt"), true);            
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw, true);
pw.println("Line 1");
pw.println("Line 2");
pw.flush();
pw.close();
```

Comment: No, you can just `flush` it.

Comment: I tried your test and can see lines appear after each println in the file

Comment: You are mistaken. The code you've posted uses a line-buffered PrintWriter. It will auto-flush on every `println()` call.

Answer (score 0):

No, in order to write what is in the writers buffer to the file, you call `flush()`. Close writes to the file because it does a flush, then closes.